# Angularjs/ui-bootstrap: popover-trigger is an invalid attribute

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i wonder why popover-trigger seems not recognized, while uib-popover is recognized. Where is located the specification for popover-trigger? I use ui-bootstrap-tpls-3.0.0-5.js, angularjs 1.6.5, bootstrap4. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it was a mistake in angular-ui-bootstrap 3.0.0-5. Solved using ui-bootstrap rather than angular-ui-bootstrap